# updating the values of variables in flutter

Tags: firebase, authentication, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

i have a variable declared in a list tile and i have many other list tiles and I want to use the value of this variable In other places since it is important , can you help?? This is the code :

```
new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Log In"),
          leading: new Icon(Icons.account_box),
          onTap: () => _signIn()
              .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
              .catchError((e) => print(e)),
          subtitle: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
              var username='';
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text('loading');
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                username= 'you are not logged in';
                return Text(username);
              } else {
                username = snapshot.data.displayName;
                return Text(username);
              }
            },
          )
        ),
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Log Out"),
          leading: new Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          onTap: () => _signOut(),
        ),
```

I want to use the variable in the next tile in the ontap function

Comment: you want to re-use the `username` variable?

Comment: yes I want to reuse it @Vignesh

Comment: Have you tried moving the scope of `username`? Eg: before `new Tile(...)`